# Scrum / Nexus - Scrum of Scrums and Daily Nexus Scrum - Clarifications

Tags: scrum, agile, team-management, agile-coach, nexus

1. How you guys resolving problem that during SOS/DNS devs making dial in and clarifying things with Product Owner?
2. What can rootcause of this? - Bad grooming?

I think this is bad practice

Comment: `Grooming` is a deprecated term. We've renamed it to `Refinement`. Grooming has bad connotations in many countries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_grooming

Comment: In addition to other needed edits, this question needs to be refactored to avoid being an opinion poll. Questions on this site need to invite canonical answers, rather than anecdotes.

Answer (score 1):

Scaled Scrum (i.e. SoS or DNS) ceremonies are expected to **synchronise information across teams**. The resolution of impediments (on scaled ceremonies) is expected to focus on the [challenges of coordination between the teams](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/scrum-of-scrums); solutions may entail agreeing to interfaces between teams, negotiating responsibility boundaries, etc.

With that in mind, unless the Product Owner belongs to another team (which shouldn't be the case), that's not the place to clarify such questions.

Besides, Scaled Scrum ceremonies are expected to be attended by the Scrum Master (or its representative from Nexus framework, which [may or may not be](https://www.scrum.org/resources/online-nexus-guide) the Scrum Master). Thus, the devs attending it are expected to be raising questions concerning their teams, as they're representing the team, not his sole developer role.

The root cause for this? Well, it's healthy to have questions raised to the PO and we should not try to avoid them. It's already hard enough for developers to not assume information, so we shouldn't hinder it when they're asking to clarify questions. Instead, it should be ensured that **the [refinement session](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/backlog-grooming/) is effective**, as you mentioned.

Nevertheless, if there's still questions, then:

- If they're of **interest of the whole team**, they can be discussed at the **end of the Daily Scrum**
- If they're of interest of a **reduced team audience**, then it can be done **after the Daily Scrum**

Comment: In Nexus the people who attend the nexus daily scrum are preferably the team members who *have* integration issues or who require/need coordination. In a self-organizing team, this is rarely the Scrum Master. Just as in the Daily Scrum in normal scrum, the Scrum Master is **not** required to attend the Nexus Daily Scrum.

Comment: I hope the team members who need clarification have access to the Product Owner, Stakeholders or end-users to clarify understanding as soon as the problem arises. Or, even better, that the teams have direct user representation in the teams or a Business Analyst as one of their development team members. That way the Product Owner may not be needed to clarify.